# Python 3.2 in anaconda

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, conda, python-3.2, pyenv

I'm trying to create an anaconda environment with Python3.2 but it seems that anaconda only supports 3.4+.
Is it possible to use Python3.2 with anaconda environment? How?

```
okuoub@iMac>> conda create -n myenv python=3.2

Solving environment: failed

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - python=3.2

Current channels:

  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/osx-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/osx-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro/osx-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

When running conda search I get only 2.7- and 3.3+:

```
okuoub@iMac>> conda search python
...
python                   2.7.14     hd74e306_15  pkgs/main
python                   2.7.14     hde5916a_29  pkgs/main
python                   2.7.14     he768d2d_19  pkgs/main
python                   2.7.14     hed931fe_16  pkgs/main
python                    3.3.0               3  pkgs/free
python                    3.3.0               4  pkgs/free
python                    3.3.1               0  pkgs/free
...
```

When running conda info:

```
okuoub@iMac>> conda info
     active environment : None
       user config file : /Users/okuoub/.condarc
 populated config files :
          conda version : 4.5.1
    conda-build version : 3.0.27
         python version : 3.6.3.final.0
       base environment : /Users/okuoub/anaconda3  (writable)
           channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/osx-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/osx-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro/osx-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro/noarch
          package cache : /Users/okuoub/anaconda3/pkgs
                          /Users/okuoub/.conda/pkgs
       envs directories : /Users/okuoub/anaconda3/envs
                          /Users/okuoub/.conda/envs
               platform : osx-64
             user-agent : conda/4.5.1 requests/2.18.4 CPython/3.6.3 Darwin/14.5.0 OSX/10.10.5
                UID:GID : 501:20
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False
```

Comment: Anaconda supports pretty nearly all versions of Python. What happens when you create a new environment with `conda create -n myenv python=3.2`?

Comment: @nekomatic I get an error, edited the question with it

Comment: OK, what output do you get from `conda search python` and from `conda info`? I'm guessing there must be something wrong with your channel configuration.

Comment: @nekomatic Added to the original message

Comment: Sorry, I've done some research and found that I was wrong: Anaconda does not support nearly all versions of Python. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Anaconda distribution [does not include support for Python 3.2](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-python.html):

> Anaconda supports Python 2.7, 3.4, 3.5 and 3.6.

I don't think this means it's impossible, just that nobody has built all the conda packages you would need to install this version. There's a [discussion on the Anaconda group](https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/d/topic/anaconda/Gn0Vy1rNmCU/discussion) about getting Python 3.2 to work but it's a few years old and doesn't conclude with a general solution.

You could try asking there again, but otherwise I think your options are to  get your code to work in 3.4 or later, or to look for some other way of doing this.