# matplotlib - module 'sip' has no attribute 'setapi'

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, visual-studio-code, attributeerror

I just set up the VS Code with all the Python extensions. Python version is 3.8.3 through Anaconda. The interpreter is venv. When I run this code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

An error shows -

```
Exception has occurred: AttributeError
module 'sip' has no attribute 'setapi'
  File "C:\test.py", line 145, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling matplotlib, but to no avail.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There seems to be an incompatibility issue using Matplotlib version 3.3 with IPython. For now, you can fix it by installing Matplotlib 3.2.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. According to another post, the Anaconda distribution does not include support for Python 3.2
https://stackoverflow.com/a/50108544/5560837

Comment: I meant Matplotlib version 3.2 not Python 3.2. I edited the answer to clear that up.

Comment: for me matplotlib==3.3.4, downgrade the matplotlib to 3.2, it worked

Comment: For reference, I also get this issue on VSCode, but when using Spyder in the same anaconda environment `%matplotlib qt5` works fine. So it's not a pure ipython issue, but something in the way ipython and VSCode work together.

Answer (score 29):

This worked for me.

```
python -m pip install matplotlib==3.2
```

Comment: i found the same issue. this was due to the different version. This solved my issue. Thanks @nuno

Comment: this works. thank you.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem. I was using PyCharm. Installing PyQt5 worked for me.

Comment: `pip install PyQt5` - worked for me. Win10. `Matplotlib 3.4.1`, `Py 3.8.5`.

Answer (score 2):

I also had the same issue, and none of the above answers worked for me. After some trial and error, it seems that pyqt and qt were causing my issues. I know you are using venv, but if you don't mind using Anaconda, the following environment should work for you:

`conda create -n matplotlib python==3.8.3 matplotlib==3.3.4 pyqt==5.9.2 qt==5.9.7`

I tested this solution on `python==3.8.3` and `python==3.7.10` using Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

PySide2 is the official Qt (v5) for Python package which is officially supported by the Qt Company.

Install this module when using matplotlib and Jupyter/IPython

```
pip install pyside2
```

There is also PySide6 which is the package for Qt (v6)

Don't ask me why pyside2 is for qt5...

Answer (score 1):

I reinstalled matplotlib to the latest version and it came out fine.

```
pip uninstall matplotlib
pip install matplotlib
```

This upgrades the matplotlib version from 3.3.4 to 3.4.2.

*I'm using python 3.7.6, windows, in a virtual environment.