# AttributeError: module 'sip' has no attribute 'setapi'

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-3.8

I am using python 3.8.5 and matplotlib 3.3.2. From the answers on another question [linked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64291087/matplotlib-module-sip-has-no-attribute-setapi), I know that there are some incompatibilities between matplotlib and python 3.8. However, due to some function updates, I need matplotlib >3.3.1.

Are there some new solutions for this incompatibility?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to make an update or answer my own question after trying for several hours... I still do not know what the cause was, but I could solve the problem by uninstalling and reinstalling.

```
conda remove qt
conda remove pyqt 
conda install qt 
conda install pyqt
```

I saw this solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41994485/how-to-fix-could-not-find-or-load-the-qt-platform-plugin-windows-while-using-m), which was for another problem. But anyway, it may help someone else having the same problem that I had.